# How do rvalue references assist in the creation of a std::swap-like function?

Tags: c++

Another, mostly unrelated question linked [this article](https://www.artima.com/articles/a-brief-introduction-to-rvalue-references) by Bjarne Stroustrup. When introducing rvalue references, he gives an example of its utility with a quick implementation of `std::swap`. Unfortunately, he never shows how rvalue references benefit this function after introducing them. He states that `move` elicits a destructive read of `a`, which is true of course, but... wouldn't this also be the case for any rvalue-based implementation? Why does he claim that specialization would be needed to optimize `swap` without rvalue references?

Comment: Some types allow move but don't allow copy. (Examples are mentioned in the linked article.) A `std::swap()` which uses copy assignment wouldn't be applicable. You had to provide specializations of `std::swap()` to make it applicable for these types. Though, that's not optimization but rather enabling at all. _The_ example for optimization are containers (mentioned in the linked article as well). Copy assignment of containers mean deep-copy but move assignment of containers means just the swap of administration data which is of constant size regardless how much the container stores.

Comment: @Scheff's Cat does the second implementation of `swap` not use move semantics already though? Or am I misunderstanding the intent of the paragraphs that follow that example?

Comment: As I understand this article, it's the motivation why an rvalue reference is needed / introduced at all. Without the rvalue reference, the problem of swap (i.e. the efficient swapping of e.g. `std::vector`) could be performed with specialization but specializations would be necessary for any other `class` with similar issues as well. RValues and move semantics provide a more general solution for this and similar issues.